# Add multi_match to Elastic Search Function Score Query

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently, I am only querying the "content" of a web page stored in elastic search for a keyword match. I would like to add the title to that equation. I am using the top code (under "MARRY THIS") and would like to somehow insert the bottom code ("WITH THIS") but can't seem to find an explanation on how to do so.

```
MARRY THIS

{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "content": "keyword"
                }
            },
            "functions": [{
                "field_value_factor": {
                    "field": "obls",
                    "factor": 0.5,
                    "modifier": "ln2p"
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "from": "0",
    "size": "100"
}

WITH THIS

{
  "multi_match" : {
    "query":    "keyword", 
    "fields": [ "title^3", "content" ] 
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out after a lot of trial and error, it looks like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "baseball",
                    "fields": ["content", "title"]
                }
            },
            "functions": [{
                "field_value_factor": {
                    "field": "obls",
                    "factor": 0.5,
                    "modifier": "ln2p"
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "from": "10",
    "size": "100"
}
```